# integrating api into spyder in python

Tags: python, nlp

this is the code for integration of Api( sentimental analysis python).i have taken this code from meaning cloud tool.
here i want to know the what is the value for url and document in payload.

input-set of words like (good,excellent,great,bad)opinion words
output-P,P+,N,N+

```
import requests

url = "https://api.meaningcloud.com/sentiment-2.1"

payload = "key=YOUR_KEY_VALUE&lang=YOUR_LANG_VALUE&txt=YOUR_TXT_VALUE&txtf=plain&url=YOUR_URL_VALUE&doc=YOUR_DOC_VALUE"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Go to https://www.meaningcloud.com/developer/sentiment-analysis/console/2.1 and click the little (i) in front of the fields.

Comment: i did not get you..where is the little(i)?